# Spring Data MongoDB @Document altering database fields

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a collection (e.g `animal`) described by the following class:

```
@Document
public class Animal {
  @Id
  public ObjectId id;
  public String name;
  public String color;
}
```

The collection has the fields `_id, name, color`.

Now I want to remove the color field from the `Animal` class, but I don't want it to be deleted from my database.

The problem is that if I simply delete the property from the `Animal` class, the `color` field (in the collection) for existing entities is deleted as well.

Any ideas how might I achieve this behavior?

Comment: No, for existing entities it will not be deleted.

Comment: I am getting exactly the opposite: when changing an entity, all removed fields are removed from the db as well

Comment: What other operation is your application doing?
Removing a field from the class does not change the db